# Remove access to file and folder in my asp-classic website

Tags: file, iis, asp-classic, permissions, file-access

I have an classic asp website and the users can upload some file that are save in a subfolder of my website.

I've just noticed that if I browse to the folder I see the list of my files. Localhost/myfiles
So i' had removed the directory browsing.

But if I know the file name I could open it : localhost/myfiles/file1.pdf

I don't care if a loggued user access the files but the problem is that even if i'm not connected I can access it.

Is there a way in classic asp to block the access, I know it's possible in .net

More : I don't want to change the position of myfiles folder and get it out of the website ...

EDIT : Even If I get out the folder from under my webSite, i'm not sure i'm gonna be able to get /save the file from the website, can someone confirm that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really good post addressing what your asking

Maybe the best option is...

Creating a page that recieves the file name in a query string, and serves the file from server-side:  http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum47/2275.htm

Not exactly an easy solution to what you're wanting to do.

There may be ways to also do this using ARR, but that could be very complex for what you're wanting to do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this don't seems to correct the problem but only hide it by not showing the file name